# setting datadource of a DataGrid nested in a parent DataList row

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple question
I have a DataList having a DataGrid in each row of it which must be filled based on one of the fields of the current row of DataList at run time.

Can anybody suggest a method to set the grid's datasource dynamically?

Thnx

Comment: You do this in datalist itemdatabound event by finding the grid control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use datalist itemdatabound event.

```
 protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
         e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {           
        GridView grd= (GridView )e.Item.FindControl("GridView1"); 
        grd.DataSource = dt;
        grd.DataBind();
    }
 }
```